AWS SageMaker Predictions and Test Data
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
import s3fs
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer

# Define the S3 path for your CSV file
import pandas as pd
import s3fs

# Define the S3 path for your CSV file
s3_path = "s3://{}/{}/{}.csv"

# Function to read file with additional checks
def read_and_check_csv(s3_path):
    fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    with fs.open(s3_path) as f:
        try:
            # Attempt to read the CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, low_memory=False)
            # Check for consistent row length
            if not df.apply(lambda x: len(x.dropna()), axis=1).nunique() == 1:
                raise ValueError("Inconsistent row lengths detected")
            print("File read successfully and seems to be in CSV format.")
            return df
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to read CSV file: {e}")
            return None

# Read and check the CSV file
df = read_and_check_csv(s3_path)

if df is not None:
    print(df.head())
else:
    print("File could not be read or is not in a valid CSV format.")


# Define indices for slicing the data
a = [50 * i for i in range(3)]
b = [40 + i for i in range(10)]
indices = [i + j for i, j in itertools.product(a, b)]

# Prepare test data
test_data = shape.iloc[indices[:-1]]
test_X = test_data.iloc[:, 1:]

# Ensure all rows have the same number of columns
min_cols = test_X.shape[1]
test_X = test_X.dropna(axis=1, how='all')  # Drop columns with all NaN values

# Verify there are no rows with different lengths
test_X = test_X.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)

# Initialize the Predictor with your SageMaker endpoint name
predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name='endpoint')

# Ensure the predictor is using the CSV serializer
predictor.serializer = CSVSerializer()

# Convert the DataFrame to the format expected by the endpoint
test_X_csv = test_X.to_csv(index=False, header=False, sep=',')

# Make predictions
try:
    predictions = predictor.predict(test_X_csv)
    # Print the predictions
    print(predictions.decode('utf-8'))
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error making predictions: {e}")


I am using this script above for my xgboost framework in aws sagemaker Jupyter labs. Before this script I am running the code below to setup the endpoint.
predictor = estimator.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.m5.2xlarge"
)

I have added in some error handling and that is where I am learning that my test file is not getting read correctly it seems. The actual error I get is:
Failed to read CSV file: Inconsistent row lengths detected
File could not be read or is not in a valid CSV format.
Error making predictions: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from primary with message "Loading csv data failed with Exception, please ensure data is in csv format:
 <class 'ValueError'>
 setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (29,) + inhomogeneous part."

Any insight on how to fix this?

It’s possible that the error is due to feeding a multi-line CSV to predictor.predict, which expects each row to be a single line. Can you adapt your code to only provide a single line of CSV per prediction?
Alternatively you can also use batch transform.
